# OS X: Can I localize the name of a folder/directory?

Tags: macos, localization, filesystems, directory

As the title mentioned.

Many system folders are displayed localized is OS X Finder. Even if it is mounted as an volume. For example, the "/Application" folder has the actual directory name "Application". But if you switch the system language, it may be displayed differently in Finder.

Can a user-created folder act like this? How can we achieve that?

Thank you at advance.

Answer (score 2):

[This SO answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/24258/104986) may helps you(I have tested).

In short, change your folder localization strings(In my case, inside ko.lproj) using [TextWrangler](http://barebones.com/products/textwrangler/) or other application(Xcode, TextEdit does not work in my case)

I add

```
    <key>Dropbox</key>
    <string>드랍박스</string>
```

to this file.

> /System/Library/CoreServices/SystemFolderLocalizations/ko.lproj/SystemFolderLocalizations.strings

You may find your localization string(English - en, Korean - ko ...)